# Does onsip-cordova plugin support android?

Tags: android, cordova, sip

i'm building an app for telecommunication that uses SIP, but i want to build a cross-platform app with cordova, but i didn't found a lot of info about that, other than two web SIP libraries, SIPML5, and onsip-cordova, i tried to use the last one, but when i followed the guide in their website, for android, the INVITE request is not sent.
So this is my problem here, and my question is : whether if this plugin doesn't support android, or there is a fix for this problem where the INVITE request is not sent. this is my console [output](https://gist.github.com/Iliyass/19708aa9bf9327b27bcd)

Answer (score 0):

I have a successful SIP implementation in cordova platform utilizing webrtc - jssip (http://jssip.net/) on the client side and an ubuntu aws instance running oversip (http://oversip.net/) as a proxy. Just include the jssip library in your app and start making SIP requests through your oversip proxy (utilizing websockets).